# Extract numbers in a data frame by conditions and determine which rows and numbers are these numbers in

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a data frame:

```
df=data.frame(co1=c(5,9,6,1,6),co2=c(8,5,4,6,2),co3=c(6,5,4,1,2),co4=c(6,1,5,3,2),co5=c(5,1,2,6,8))
rownames(df)=c('row1','row2','row3','row4','row5')
df
#      co1 co2 co3 co4 co5
#row1   5   8   6   6   5
#row2   9   5   5   1   1
#row3   6   4   4   5   2
#row4   1   6   1   3   6
#row5   6   2   2   2   8
```

How can I select numbers whose values are greater than 5? And how to determine which row and column are these numbers in? That is, how do I get a data frame like this:

```
# rownames  colnames  value
#   row1      col2      8
#   row1      col3      6
#   row1      col4      6
#   row2      col1      9
#   row3      col1      6
#   ...       ...      ...
```

Comment: Try with `which` i.e. `i1 <- which(df > 5, arr.ind=TRUE); data.frame(rownames = rownames(df)[i1[,1]], colnames = colnames(df)[i1[,2]], value = df[i1])` or `library(reshape2);subset(melt(as.matrix(df)), value>5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `melt` with `subset`

```
library(reshape2)
subset(melt(as.matrix(df)), value>5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or if you prefer tidyverse,

```
library(tidyverse)
  df %>%
  rownames_to_column() %>%
  gather(colname,value,-rowname) %>%
  filter(value > 5)
```

Best regards,
Hans